# Permutation and Combination in a chess game with prediction

Tags: permutations, combinations

Ques. The result of 20 chess games (win,lose,draw) have to be predicted.How many different forecasts can contain exactly 15 correct details

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- In such a forecast, how many games are guessed wrong ?
- How many ways of choosing the wrongly-guessed games ?
- How many ways of guessing wrong a particular game ?
- How many ways of guessing wrong five games ?